# Cannot get my Mismatchexception to work properly with switch

Tags: java, error-handling, switch-statement

PROBLEM IS SOLVED.

So i'm finishing up my assignment, the last thing to do is to implement some easy error handling, but it turns out that I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have 5 cases which takes input 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. It works fine.

But if input isn't a number, it should display a message, and let the user enter some new input. After each task is completed, you should be presented with the menu and be able to make a new coice.

I can print the message, but I am not able to take new input. I understand the problem and why i occurs, but I have no idea on how to actually solve it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ObscureLovecraft {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Looking for files and opening scanner
        File file = new File("./lovecraft.txt");
        File readObscure = new File("./obscure.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Printing UI

        printMenu();

        // Taking input, looping until case 0 is executed
        // Printing menu after each iteration
        // Switch, prints a new menu after every iteration
        try {
        int input = sc.nextInt();

            while (input != 0) {

                switch (input) {
                case 1:
                    writeObscure(file);
                    printMenu();
                    input = sc.nextInt();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    translateObscure(readObscure);
                    printMenu();
                    input = sc.nextInt();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    printObscure();
                    printMenu();
                    input = sc.nextInt();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    printTranslated();
                    printMenu();
                    input = sc.nextInt();
                    break;

                case 0:
                    kill();
                    break;

                }
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("You must use numbers.");
            sc.nextInt();
        }

        sc.close();

        System.out.println(":(");

    }

    public static void switches() {

    }

    /**
     * Just a method printing our menu
     */
    public static void printMenu() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Obscure");
        System.out.println("=======");
        System.out.println("1. Make obscure");
        System.out.println("2. Make readable");
        System.out.println("3. Print obscure");
        System.out.println("4. Print readable");
        System.out.println("0. Exit");
    }

    /**
     * Method which will print the "obscured" version of the text
     * 
     * @param file path to the file
     */
    public static void writeObscure(File file) {
        // Create new output file, creating PrintWriter, StringBuilder and placeholder
        // for the text
        File outFile = new File("./obscure.txt");
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outFile);
            Scanner fileSc = new Scanner(file);
            String text = "";

            // Placeholder for chars, looping through the file, adding it to placeholder
            // text, with new line
            char c;
            while (fileSc.hasNextLine()) {
                text = (fileSc.nextLine() + "\n");
                // Looping through the text, taking each character, pushing it 3 steps in the
                // alphabet
                // Taking care of z/Z pushing it to a/A, should maybe be c/C? Oh well.
                // Appending it to the stringbuilder in the new order
                // Casting char to int, to get ascii value
                for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                    c = text.charAt(i);
                    if (c == 'z') {
                        buf.append('a');
                    } else if (c == 'Z') {
                        buf.append('A');
                    } else {
                        int ascii = (int) c;
                        char nextChar = (char) (ascii + 3);
                        buf.append(nextChar);
                    }

                }
            }
            fileSc.close();

            // Printing and closing
            pw.print(buf);
            pw.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Seems like a file gone missing, check error message: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Printing stacktrace: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method which will translate the obscured text to normal, Basically same as
     * the method above, but in reversed order
     * 
     * @param file
     */
    public static void translateObscure(File file) {
        // Read the file:
        StringBuilder obsBuf = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            Scanner readSC = new Scanner(file);
            // Print the file
            File printReadable = new File("./readableLovecraft.txt");
            PrintWriter pwRead = new PrintWriter(printReadable);

            // Text
            String readableText = "";
            char readC;

            // Loop thru
            // Something weird happend with empty lines,
            // Had to manually skip them
            while (readSC.hasNextLine()) {
                readableText = (readSC.nextLine() + "\n");

                for (int i = 0; i < readableText.length(); i++) {
                    readC = readableText.charAt(i);
                    if (readC == '\n') {
                        obsBuf.append(readC);
                    } else if (readC == 'z') {
                        obsBuf.append('a');
                    } else if (readC == 'Z') {
                        obsBuf.append('z');
                    } else {
                        int ascii = (int) readC;
                        char nextChar = (char) (ascii - 3);
                        obsBuf.append(nextChar);
                    }
                }

            }
            readSC.close();

            // Printing and closing
            pwRead.print(obsBuf);
            pwRead.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Seems like a file gone missing, check error message: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Printing stacktrace: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Simple method which loops through the text and prints it
     */
    public static void printObscure() {
        File readOutFile = new File("./obscure.txt");
        try {

            Scanner fileSc = new Scanner(readOutFile);
            String readText = "";
            while (fileSc.hasNextLine()) {
                readText = (fileSc.nextLine());
                System.out.println(readText);
            }
            fileSc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Seems like a file gone missing, check error message: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Printing stacktrace: ");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    /**
     * Simple method which loops through the text and prints it
     */
    public static void printTranslated() {
        File readReadOutFile = new File("./readableLovecraft.txt");
        String readReadText = "";
        Scanner fileSc;
        try {
            fileSc = new Scanner(readReadOutFile);

            while (fileSc.hasNextLine()) {
                readReadText = (fileSc.nextLine() + "\n");
                System.out.println(readReadText);

            }
            fileSc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Seems like a file gone missing, check error message: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Printing stacktrace: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method which kills the program
     */
    public static void kill() {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: show complete code

Comment: I've edited the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1- Create a new method and put your logic into it
>
> 2- Delete `while` from your code
>
> 3- Throws `InputMismatchException` in default block
>
> 4- Call the `newMethod()`  in `cases` instead of `input = sc.nextInt.` (recursive)
>
> 5- Call the `newMethod()`  in catch block (recursive)

```
public static void newMethod() {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {

            int input = sc.nextInt();

            switch (input) {
                case 1:
                    writeObscure(file);
                    printMenu();
                    newMethod();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    translateObscure(readObscure);
                    printMenu();
                    newMethod();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    printObscure();
                    printMenu();
                    newMethod();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    printTranslated();
                    printMenu();
                    newMethod();
                    break;

                case 0:
                    kill();
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("You must use numbers.");
            newMethod();
        }

      sc.close();

}
```

> Change your `main` method like this

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

            File file = new File("./lovecraft.txt");
            File readObscure = new File("./obscure.txt");
            printMenu();
            
            //Call new Method
            newMethod();
            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check out line 60.  You need to read to the end of the line and then read for the next integer.  This fixes your current problem but you still have others

```html
   import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ObscureLovecraft {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Looking for files and opening scanner
    File file = new File("./lovecraft.txt");
    File readObscure = new File("./obscure.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Printing UI

    printMenu();

    // Taking input, looping until case 0 is executed
    // Printing menu after each iteration
    // Switch, prints a new menu after every iteration
    while (true) {
       try {
       int input = sc.nextInt();

        

            switch (input) {
            case 1:
                writeObscure(file);
                printMenu();
                input = sc.nextInt();
                break;

            case 2:
                translateObscure(readObscure);
                printMenu();
                input = sc.nextInt();
                break;

            case 3:
                printObscure();
                printMenu();
                input = sc.nextInt();
                break;

            case 4:
                printTranslated();
                printMenu();
                input = sc.nextInt();
                break;

            case 0:
                kill();
                break;

            }
        
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("You must use numbers.");
        sc.nextLine();
       
    }
    
    

    System.out.println(":(");
}

   

}

public static void switches() {

}

/**
 * Just a method printing our menu
 */
public static void printMenu() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Obscure");
    System.out.println("=======");
    System.out.println("1. Make obscure");
    System.out.println("2. Make readable");
    System.out.println("3. Print obscure");
    System.out.println("4. Print readable");
    System.out.println("0. Exit");
}

/**
 * Method which will print the "obscured" version of the text
 * 
 * @param file path to the file
 */
public static void writeObscure(File file) {
    // Create new output file, creating PrintWriter, StringBuilder and placeholder
    // for the text
    File outFile = new File("./obscure.txt");
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outFile);
        Scanner fileSc = new Scanner(file);
        String text = "";

        // Placeholder for chars, looping through the file, adding it to placeholder
        // text, with new line
        char c;
        while (fileSc.hasNextLine()) {
            text = (fileSc.nextLine() + "\n");
            // Looping through the text, taking each character, pushing it 3 steps in the
            // alphabet
            // Taking care of z/Z pushing it to a/A, should maybe be c/C? Oh well.
            // Appending it to the stringbuilder in the new order
            // Casting char to int, to get ascii value
            for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                c = text.charAt(i);
                if (c == 'z') {
                    buf.append('a');
                } else if (c == 'Z') {
                    buf.append('A');
                } else {
                    int ascii = (int) c;
                    char nextChar = (char) (ascii + 3);
                    buf.append(nextChar);
                }

            }
        }
        fileSc.close();

        // Printing and closing
        pw.print(buf);
        pw.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Seems like a file gone missing, check error message: " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Printing stacktrace: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Method which will translate the obscured text to normal, Basically same as
 * the method above, but in reversed order
 * 
 * @param file
 */
public static void translateObscure(File file) {
    // Read the file:
    StringBuilder obsBuf = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Scanner readSC = new Scanner(file);
        // Print the file
        File printReadable = new File("./readableLovecraft.txt");
        PrintWriter pwRead = new PrintWriter(printReadable);

        // Text
        String readableText = "";
        char readC;

        // Loop thru
        // Something weird happend with empty lines,
        // Had to manually skip them
        while (readSC.hasNextLine()) {
            readableText = (readSC.nextLine() + "\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < readableText.length(); i++) {
                readC = readableText.charAt(i);
                if (readC == '\n') {
                    obsBuf.append(readC);
                } else if (readC == 'z') {
                    obsBuf.append('a');
                } else if (readC == 'Z') {
                    obsBuf.append('z');
                } else {
                    int ascii = (int) readC;
                    char nextChar = (char) (ascii - 3);
                    obsBuf.append(nextChar);
                }
            }

        }
        readSC.close();

        // Printing and closing
        pwRead.print(obsBuf);
        pwRead.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Seems like a file gone missing, check error message: " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Printing stacktrace: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Simple method which loops through the text and prints it
 */
public static void printObscure() {
    File readOutFile = new File("./obscure.txt");
    try {

        Scanner fileSc = new Scanner(readOutFile);
        String readText = "";
        while (fileSc.hasNextLine()) {
            readText = (fileSc.nextLine());
            System.out.println(readText);
        }
        fileSc.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Seems like a file gone missing, check error message: " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Printing stacktrace: ");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

/**
 * Simple method which loops through the text and prints it
 */
public static void printTranslated() {
    File readReadOutFile = new File("./readableLovecraft.txt");
    String readReadText = "";
    Scanner fileSc;
    try {
        fileSc = new Scanner(readReadOutFile);

        while (fileSc.hasNextLine()) {
            readReadText = (fileSc.nextLine() + "\n");
            System.out.println(readReadText);

        }
        fileSc.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Seems like a file gone missing, check error message: " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Printing stacktrace: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Method which kills the program
 */
public static void kill() {
    System.exit(1);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That made it way better, however, the application finishes when I've entered a faulty input, and tries to enter a new one. I does not iterate back to the switch. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: you need to add a default case to your switch